# Can't figure out what kind of keyframe this is?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

Can't figure out how to locate this keyframe, there's a tall yellowish green line on my timeline but I don't know what it represents tried narrowing things down by using the outliner but still can't figure it out.

[image: blender timeline]

Comment: open the [dope sheet window](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/dope_sheet/index.html?highlight=dope%20sheet) you should be able to determine to what keyframe represents

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. Including a .blend file can help people determine what your problem is. Please upload yours to [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Thank you!

Comment: Ah I found it, I did look at the dope sheet earlier but didn't see anything until I switch it to Grease Pencil, some how I accidentally set a key. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Please add that as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This yellow-green line is set whenever using the Grease Pencil tool on the selected frame:

[image]